# Linking items in Sparx Enterprise Architect Glossary

Tags: enterprise-architect, glossary, traceability

I'm looking for a way to link several items with each other in the Sparx Enterprise Architect Glossary. Is this a possibility?

Example

| Term | Definition | Links to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fact | Something that happend | Follow-up Registration |
| Follow-up | Action following a fact | Result |
| Registration | Writing the fact down | - |
| Result | The effect of the follow-up | - |

I'm looking for a way to register the third column making it easier to have a traceability within the glossary.

Comment: I'd guess the answer will be: not possible. t_glossary has just Term, Type, Meaning and ID. No space for a link.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with the standard glossary, but you can with the new glossary modes (since v15)
See the [manual](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/modeling/glossary_package_struct.html) for more info.

This new method allows you to create elements for glossary items. And since they are elements, you can link them to other elements.

You can even use the classes of your existing data model. Just add them to a glossary diagram, and they are included in the glossary.

Comment: Hey wow. They are already implementing what I do myself since ages with EA.